# Странное поведение визуального редактора на сайте

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, с такой проблеммой: есть сайт, где стоит визуальный редактор, когда какой-либо пользователь, админ и т.д. первый раз желает воспользоваться им то он отображается и работает - всё хорошо, затем после какой-либо перегрузки страницы этот редактор изчезает и больше не появляется, хотя если очистить кеш в браузере, то он снова появляется до первой перегрузки страницы. Подскажите, что сделать чтобы редактор работал нормально без таких косяков?  Думаю что-нибудь нужно сделать с правами на файлы, но... первый раз с такой проблеммой столкнулся.
Заранее спасибо за помощь!)

Comment: Уточните, что за редактор - самописный или готовый, и если готовый, то какой.

Comment: Прошу прощение за возможно неправильное подозрение, но складывается впечатление как будто вы не заплатили программисту и он оставил вам демонстрационный вариант. В любом случае @VioLet прав, вам нужно сказать как называется редактор. Если он не самописный, но вы не знаете как узнать название, можно попробовать открыть исходный код страницы(html) и написать сюда все строчки похожие на "<script type='text/javascript' src='здесь какой то путь до файла.js'></script>", они должны быть в где то в начале.

Comment: редактор, который там установлен - tinymce, CMS - Moodle - это CMS для образовательных сайтов, на локальном сервере всё работало, а вот после переноса на хостинг появился этот касяк. Программист, который делал этот сайт это я.

Comment: а во всех браузерах исчезает редактор?

Comment: Да, во всех, сейчас решил в тех.поддержку хостинга написать, может они что-нибудь посоветуют

Comment: @Rumato если вы "сделали" сайт в CMS то вы не программист а венбмастер а программист это человек знающий хотя бы Java Script :)

Comment: Rules, Я сам, без тебя решу кто я, тем  более Javascript слитно пишется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая же найденная яндексом [ссылка](http://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=171674). Впрочем, решения там нет, только сумбур и непонимание.

Comment: beardog, спасибо за ссылку, там проблема была совсем в другом, а именно в хостинге, Moodle, жрёт довольно много ресурсов, поэтому переход на другой более дорогой хостинг решил все проблемы, там и некоторые модули не устанавливались, если кто-нибудь решит использовать эту CMS, то могу посоветовать хостинг TimeWeb. А вообще на том же Yii можно сделать аналогичную Moodle систему, которая будет работать в разы быстрее и жрать намного меньше ресурсов.